# Watchdog configuration on Stellaris Launchpad LM4F120

Tags: c, embedded

I try to configure the watchdog timer on Stellaris Launchpad LM4F120.

The code is the following:

```
void configure_watchdog(void) {
    SYSCTL_RCGCWD_R = 0x1; /* Enabling Clock for WD0 */
    WATCHDOG0_LOAD_R = 0xffffffff; /* Setting initial value */
    WATCHDOG0_CTL_R = WDT_CTL_INTEN; /* Enabling interrupt generation */
}
```

This supposed to be enough in accordance to the datasheet.

The problem is that controller always falls to `FaultISR` and resets after it. I can't understand why.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: The controller does not reset. It just goes to `FaultISR`

Comment: Immediately? Or just after the watchdog expires?

Comment: @CarlNorum I can't understand it, as with the debugger it doesn't fail. But it seems to happen after the expiring. BTW, if I don't enable the interrupt, it seems to work fine.

Comment: The debugger probably disables the watchdog or chokes its interrupt.  A watchdog is *supposed* to reset your machine.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CarlNorum Actually, I supposed to use it as a kind of downcounter. Also from the datasheet it is not clear that watchdog, configured this way supposed to reset system.

This is a quote from datasheet:
■ 32-bit down counter with a programmable load register
■ Separate watchdog clock with an enable
■ Programmable interrupt generation logic with interrupt masking and optional NMI function
■ Lock register protection from runaway software
■ Reset generation logic with an enable/disable
■ User-enabled stalling when the microcontroller asserts the CPU Halt flag during debug

Comment: sorry - I'm not familiar with that part.  It says the reset generation has enable/disable, why not just disable it then?

Comment: @CarlNorum Well that is the question. It is disabled on reset.

Answer (score 2):

Jumping to an ISR when the watchdog expires sounds like the correct behavior.  What exactly are you doing inside your ISR code?  If you are resetting the watchdog inside the ISR, then you shouldn't be seeing the microcontroller reset itself (based on your posted configuration code, at least).  After you set up the watchdog, read the configuration register back out and make sure that it holds the value that you expect.  Some of the bits in that register can only be set under certain circumstances, and it's possible that you're not running with the settings that you think you're using.

You mentioned that you were trying to use the watchdog timer as a generic downcounter.  Could you use one of the general-purpose timers instead of the watchdog?  You would still get an interrupt when time expired, but regular timers don't have the ability to reset the entire system.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep servicing the watchdog, otherwise it times out and calls whatever is setup for that exception.  `FaultISR` would appear to be that in your case.

If you want the watchdog to do something else on the timeout you need to figure out how your particular toolchain connects functions to exception sources and map your new function correctly.

If you don't want the watchdog to expire (which is usually what it's there for, to catch  errant code) then you need to service it regularly.  The compiler vendor often provides a function or intrinsic to do this.